# firefox »find as you type« is conflicting with JavaScript key events

Tags: javascript, firefox

Firefox has »find as you type« functionality, which is super awesome. But when developing JavaScript web applications and I want to react on key events only the first key is captured, subsequent keys all go to the find field.

Is there a way to disable this with vanilla JS? (no frameworks such as MooTools)

I tried `return false;` at the end of the event handler, but it does not work.

Comment: @skaffman: this has nothing to do with some kind of autocomplete, i really meant firefox' "find as you type" here. autocomplete is misleading and hints at autocompletion in input fields or similar – which is not what i am after

Comment: is this a web page or a FF addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `preventDefault()` method on the `event` object?

Also try to see the difference between binding to `keyup/keydown/keypress` (or maybe all of them) and see if there is a difference in controlling the events that way

Comment: yes, i tried `event.stop();`, `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;`

Comment: @knittl: what version of firefox are you using for testing?

Comment: ok, `event.preventDefault()` did the trick in the end. i don't know why it was not working before, but when putting `preventDefault()` as the first call in the event handler it works. weird enough sometimes it even works when called last.

also, only `keydown` needs to be handled specially for firefox to not switch to 'find as you type'. `keyup` is handled after `keydown` and does not trigger this behavior

Comment: @neil, don't worry, i'll accept it, but i'll give this question a little bit more time